# HELP loading strings for levels of my iphone game in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

So im conceptually stuck building my app. I've read lots of forums but I think I need to try a new route. Heres what im trying to do.

I created a game where each level loads a different string for the user to play with. Right now the strings for the levels are stored in a plist. There are 5 categories (arrays) each of which contains 20 different strings (ie 20 levels) so there are 100 levels total.

When the user starts the game they reach the "LevelSelect" view which consists of a picker. The picker has two components. the first component is a list of categories, and the second component is the list of levels in that category. The user selects which of the levels they want to play, then press a "Start" button to bring up the "GamePlay" view (an entirely different set of .h, .m, and .xib files).

***MY PROBLEM:*** I dont know how to make the selected level appear on the screen in the Gameplay class. I have all the machinery of the game working, so if I create a string in the viewDidLoad, the game appears to work fine, but I want to have the string for that level come onto the screen when that level is selected and the user presses start.

**MY QUESTION: How do I pass the string from LevelSelect to GamePlay?**

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear.  Are you asking a) how to pass the string from your LevelSelect view to your GamePlay view so that the user's selected string appears in the GamePlay view, or b) how to present the string within your GamePlay view?

Comment: Hey thanks good point. I mean question a. I'll edit the question to make that clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `LevelSelect` and `GamePlay` are both subclasses of `UIViewController`.  The user chooses the level he wants to play through the `LevelSelect` view controller.  It sounds like you already know how to display the view for the `GamePlay` view controller.  You just don't know how to pass a string to that view controller before you display it.

When the user presses the start button, I presume that you're currently constructing and presenting your `GamePlay` view controller with code that looks something like this:

```
- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    GamePlay *gamePlayViewController = [[[GamePlay alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:gamePlayViewController animated:NO];
}
```

Your goal is give your `GamePlay` view controller a `levelString` property that you can set like this:

```
- (IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    GamePlay *gamePlayViewController = [[[GamePlay alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
    gamePlay.levelString = self.selectedLevelString;
    [self presentModalViewController:gamePlayViewController animated:NO];
}
```

where `self.selectedLevelString` is the string for the level the user selected in the picker.

To achieve this you'll need to declare the property in your GamePlay.h file like this:

```
@interface GamePlay : UIViewController {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *levelString;
@end
```

In your GamePlay.m file you'll need to synthesize this property and release it in your dealloc method like this:

```
@implementation GamePlay
@synthesize levelString;

- (void)dealloc {
    self.levelString = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

This gives your GamePlay controller a `levelString` property, which you can set from your `LevelSelect` view controller as shown above.  Then within any method in the `GamePlay` view controller, you can access this string using `self.levelString`.

By the way, my example code for `startButtonPressed:` above presumes that you have a property on your `LevelSelect` view controller called `selectedLevelString`.  You can declare this property the exact same way we declared the `levelString` property on `GamePlay`.  You can set this string as appropriate when the user selects a level in `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`.